# What does `g8` do when installing Typesafe Stack 2.0

Tags: scala, typesafe-stack

So I just installed the Typesafe Stack via the universal install (download a .zip and un-zipping it into my `/usr/local` directory. I looked at the website and it mentioned `sbt` and `g8`, so I first typed `sbt` to see what would happen and it just gave me a little error about how there was no project in the current directoy. Then I typed `g8` and it started downloading a bunch of stuff... though I'm not sure what. Can anyone tell me? Picture attached.

Additionally, does the Typesafe stack come with Scala and Akka? The website seems to say it does, but if I remove my original Scala 2.9 path from `.bash_profile` and then restart Terminal, it complains that it doesn't exist.

[image: g8]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The universal install comes with a README. It says:

> g8 is a project templating tool.  You can use this to generate a quick
>   project outline for one of the libraries in the typesafe stack. 
>   Examples  include:
>
> - g8 typesafehub/akka-java-maven
> - g8 typesafehub/akka-scala-sbt
> - g8 typesafehub/play-scala
> - g8 typesafehub/play-java

Why don't you give one of those a try? After creating your project, cd into the directory and start sbt.

Comment: I see, but what does typing `g8` by itself do? Does it just install the files `g8` needs?

Comment: Also, what do I need to do to complete wipe it from my system? I want to remove the Typesafe stack completely, and then "properly" install it via Homebrew so I can get the whole package (Scala, Akka, SBT, g8). Do I just need to remove the folder `typesafe-stack` ?

Comment: If I run g8 I get a nice usage message, i.e. running it without arguments just prints some messages and then stops. I think removing the exploded archive will do the job. There might already be some artifacts from g8, sbt, etc. in your home directory, but they probably won't hurt.